# Raw use of parameterized class 'RecyclerView.Adapter'

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, adapter

I'm developing an app which requires different adapters depending on condition.

My code is-

```
RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;

    if(condition) adapter=adapter1;
    else adapter=adapter2;

    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

[Attached image for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJJK9.png)

Code is working absolutely fine on every version of android but receiving a warning- Raw use of parameterized class 'RecyclerView.Adapter'. Tried searching but unable to resolve warning. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your question needs supporting information like code and error messages. Please read [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). This page will help you to improve your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest If I were you I would probably ignore the warning, but doing something like:

```java
if(condition) recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter1);
else recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter2);
```

would probably make the warning "go away"

Comment: Not a blocker so ignoring it. Thanks!!